# Clojure: CSS / DOM like UI for Java

Tags: java, user-interface, clojure

### Notes:

The answer is NOT clojurescript. I want to code in Clojure, not ClojureScript.

### Context:

I like the CSS/DOM model for user interfaces more than I like Java's Graphics2D.

### Question:

Is there some way / some project that embeds a WebKit of sorts into a Java Application? I would like to be able to code in Java, but also be able to have a GUI which I can control/manipulate via CSS/DOM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [JavaFX 2.0 scene graph](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/scenegraph/jfxpub-scenegraph.htm) is somewhat similar in concept to a DOM, and you can [skin it using CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm).

There is a Java API, so you should be able to use this fairly easily from Clojure.

Comment: JavaFX includes a wrapped WebKit Engine, with [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) on how to use it.  The wrapped engine exposes a [Java based DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#documentProperty%28%29) allowing you to control/manipulate the DOM via Java if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly CSS/DOM, but [seesaw](http://github.com/daveray/seesaw) allows to query Swing widget hierarchies with CSS-like selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of more-or-less mature GUI libraries [here](http://clojure-libraries.appspot.com/cat/GUI).

An above-mentioned Seesaw can fit. GUIFTW uses a CSS-like stylesheets for describing the UI and may also meet your needs but it wasn't updated for a year now.